# Using Boost Event Logger in a MFC Application: The description for Event ID cannot be found

Tags: c++, logging, mfc, event-log, boost-log

I'm trying to use Boost Log library sending events to Windows Event Log. I made plain C++ test application for my custom logger and everything was fine.
When I used the logger in a MFC application, the generated events visible in EventViewer have this error

> The description for Event ID 259 from source MFCApplication1 cannot
>   be found....

As I read in [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html#log.detailed.sink_backends.event_log) **basic_simple_event_log_backend** "contains all resources that are needed for the Event Viewer to function properly, and registers the Boost.Log library in the Windows registry in order to populate itself as the container of these resources." but I guess something failed.

Any idea how to use it in a MFC application? I'm using Boost 1.59 32bit and VS2013.

For reproduction I reduced the MFC application to a single cpp file without any resources:

```
#define VC_EXTRALEAN
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#define _AFX_ALL_WARNINGS
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/keyword.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sink.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/event_log_backend.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace logging
{
    enum severity_level
    {
        fatal,
        error,
        warning,
        info,
        debug,
        trace,
    };

    typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<severity_level> dispatcher_type;
    dispatcher_type disp;

    BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD( severity, "Severity", severity_level)

    void init( const std::string& appName)
    {
        namespace lg        = boost::log;
        namespace src       = boost::log::sources;
        namespace sinks     = boost::log::sinks;
        namespace keyword   = boost::log::keywords;
        namespace expr      = boost::log::expressions;
        namespace attrs     = boost::log::attributes;

        typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::simple_event_log_backend> evsink;
        auto sink = boost::make_shared<evsink>( keyword::log_source = appName);
        sink->set_formatter( expr::stream << expr::smessage);

        sinks::event_log::custom_event_type_mapping<severity_level> mapping( severity.get_name());
        mapping[ fatal]     = sinks::event_log::error;
        mapping[ error]     = sinks::event_log::error;
        mapping[ warning]   = sinks::event_log::warning;
        mapping[ info]      = sinks::event_log::info;
        mapping[ debug]     = sinks::event_log::info;
        mapping[ trace]     = sinks::event_log::info;

        sink->locked_backend()->set_event_type_mapper( mapping);
        sink->set_filter( severity < info);
        lg::core::get()->add_sink( sink);
    }
}

#define LOG_ERROR BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();BOOST_LOG_SEV(logging::disp, logging::error)

class CMFCApplication1App : public CWinApp
{
public:
    const std::string appName = "MFCApplication1";

    CMFCApplication1App()
    {
        if ( 0)
        {
            logging::init( appName);

            LOG_ERROR << "hello1"; // // leads to a failed assert in
            //>MFCApplication1.exe!boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attributes::named_scope::impl>::operator->() Line 174   C++
            // MFCApplication1.exe!boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attributes::named_scope::push_scope(const boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attributes::named_scope_entry & entry) Line 289    C++
            // MFCApplication1.exe!boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attributes::named_scope::sentry::sentry(const boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::basic_string_literal<char,std::char_traits<char> > & sn, const boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::basic_string_literal<char,std::char_traits<char> > & fn, unsigned int ln, boost::log::v2s_mt_nt5::attributes::named_scope_entry::scope_name_type t) Line 376    C++
            // MFCApplication1.exe!CMFCApplication1App::CMFCApplication1App() Line 71   C++
            // MFCApplication1.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'theApp''() Line 92 C++
        }
    }

    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        if ( 1)
        {
            logging::init( appName);

            LOG_ERROR << "hello2"; // leads to unknown event id
            // The description for Event ID 259 from source MFCApplication1 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
            // If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
            // The following information was included with the event: 
            // hello2
            // The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file
        }

        return TRUE;
    }

    virtual int ExitInstance()
    {
        return CWinApp::ExitInstance();
    }
};

CMFCApplication1App theApp;
```